# First Post suggests an answer from a "new user" who is 3+ years old with 1800 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

NB: I'm not sure if this is actually a bug, or if I just don't know enough about what constitutes a new user. It just seems off to me.

The first post in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1376311

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqYOr.png):
[image: Screenshot]

In the context of reviews, is a new user just someone who has never posted an answer no matter their age or rep?

Also: How is it possible for a user to have -1 other answers? Could this be related?

Comment: That was a review audit (that post was deleted days ago). I'm not sure that the review audits pay attention to which review queue they actually belong in, they're just thrown in there to make sure you're paying attention (though they probably *should* be relevant). You obviously are if you noticed it wasn't even a first post.

Comment: Well, I'm obviously not paying *enough* attention... I didn't even notice that the user had 76 answers :) Should I delete this question?

Comment: @ithcy: That it wasn't even his first answer makes the question all the more valid why it did show up in the first answers queue.

Comment: @sth animuson's comment that it was a review audit makes sense. I just didn't take action on the review, so I never got to the "thanks for paying attention" message that displays after an audit. The "-1 other answers" bit still seems off to me, though.

Comment: @itchy: Nor does saying that the question has 0 answers when you're being shown an answer to the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That review item was an *audit*: a fake review item designed to trip up bad/inattentive reviewers.

There is an [outstanding request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165389/do-not-display-the-posting-time-user-card-in-review-it-makes-audits-easily-dete) on Meta to make the audits less obvious.