# Review Audit Giveaway

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I just came across my first review audit over on SuperUser, but it was a bit of a giveaway:

[image]

Clicking through to the question shows there are actually 0 answers (as being a review-audit, this post is already deleted) but as `other answers` obviously subtracts the current review answer, it's left with a -1.

Perhaps the `other answers` field shouldn't have 1 subtracted from it in the event of an audit?

Comment: *"Nor does saying that the question has 0 answers when you're being shown an answer to the question..."* [Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164683/first-post-suggests-an-answer-from-a-new-user-who-is-3-years-old-with-1800-re#comment480250_164683)

Comment: Isn't the point of an audit to make sure you are paying attention? If you see this, you are paying attention. Really no need to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, good eye - this will be fixed up in the next build.

Comment: Hey Geoff, don't know if this is related to the fix or a new bug, but the other answers count now seems to have a `)` after it on normal reviews...

Comment: Doh - yes it was.  Pushing a fix.