# Obviously wrong answer count in review reveals it's an audit at a glance

Tags: bug, review-audits

In the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ of review tests (audits)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172), it is mentioned:

> Also, if you find something in the review audit system that makes
> audits extremely obvious (as in one can tell that a review is an audit
> in just a few seconds, with little to no extra investigation), feel
> free to report that flaw.

So, the goal of this post is to report such a flaw.

[image: Screenshot of review test (audit)]

[This is the audit in question](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1081301).

In the above screenshot we can notice that the question has 0 answers. So it's pretty obvious to the reviewer that this review is an audit.

If the answer we are looking at is deleted, but the question is shown in its current state, it will cause the *answer* count not to be the number of other answers +1, as it always should be.

This flaw is immediately obvious if one is looking for it, so it seems highly exploitable.

I asked about this on [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19292/1103140) and [one of the moderators in Ask Ubuntu does agree](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19293/1103140) that this is a flaw which needs to be reported.

Comment: This is by-design. Audits aren't meant to be hard. The fact that you notice the amount of answers on the question is already a sign that you are paying attention. You'd be amazed how many would fail an audit like this, because they aren't paying attention.

Comment: @Luuklag Dedicated robo-reviewers would look for any easy giveaways like this, I think. I doubt it's by design that these numbers get mismatched when the post is deleted. Also, mods can't remove audits...

Comment: :p it used to say “other answers: -1”: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165094/323179

Comment: I was the one who added that paragraph to the FAQ. The idea was that *obvious* ways to detect audits, as in those that can be exploited by a robo-reviewer to pass them while continuing their robo-reviewing, are OK to report. I'm not entirely sure that this constitutes such a thing, but I'll let others discuss it. In the meantime, I'll edit that paragraph to more clearly state its purpose.

Comment: See [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/4642212).

Comment: Dedicated robo-reviewers have even easier tells than the number of answers being zero. A quick glance at the network tab reveals so.

Comment: @JohnDvorak What is network tab?

Comment: network tab of the developer tools in (firefox|chrome)

Comment: Is there a notice when you pass a review? I've done hundreds of reviews now, and I've never seen one of these mysterious audits you guys keep talking about.

Comment: @SurpriseDog If we pass a review audit, the website will say you've passed the review audit. Read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/846219) for more information. BTW, review audits are currently active only on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Software Engineering, Ask Ubuntu, Mathematics, Stack Overflow em Português, and Stack Overflow en Español.

Comment: @technastic_tc Why is it only limited to those sites?

Comment: @SurpriseDog I'm not sure of the reason. But do check this comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/861317

Comment: "the question has 0 answers. So it's pretty obvious to the reviewer that this review is an audit." How so? Some questions remain unanswered without being an audit.

Comment: @Mast I guess you didn't get the point. The review here is about a *first answer by a new user*. If you can see at the bottom right of the screenshot, it's mentioned that the question has 0 answers. So how come I review an answer when there are no answers for the question? Got my point?