# Does the review queue randomly fires up old questions?

Tags: support, review

Why does the review queue sometime shows me a “first post” to review that is dated a month ago?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do not display the posting time/user card in review; it makes audits easily detectable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165389/do-not-display-the-posting-time-user-card-in-review-it-makes-audits-easily-dete)

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons, for example:

- the threshold for the queue is adapted so olders posts are now available.
- the post is a honeypot.
- the post is a random post too lure honeypot spotters by date.

Comment: You're missing about ∞ degrees of meta in your list ;-)