# Audit first-post review not anonymized (3.5k user answer used as the audit)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, review-audits

This could be a bug affecting the whole StackExchange network, but it has happened on StackOverflow (this is the reason I post this here)

I have posted earlier this question on Meta.SO :
[How can an answer posted by a 3.5k rep user get used as an Audit in the "First-Post" review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268162/how-can-an-answer-posted-by-a-3-5k-rep-user-get-used-as-an-audit-in-the-first-p)

Short resume :
In the "First-Post" review queue, there was an *obvious* audit where there was a "First-Post" from a 3.5k rep user. It was **obviously** not a first post, nor a new user.

> Screenshot taken **before** the audit was completed
> [image: Audit Screenshot]

[Some](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2293162#2293162) are saying that the Usercard should of been "anonymized". This means that this is a bug (as it still showed the **real** Usercard).

(Not a duplicate to [First Post suggests an answer from a "new user" who is 3+ years old with 1800 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164683/first-post-suggests-an-answer-from-a-new-user-who-is-3-years-old-with-1800-re) as the feature (anonymizing) wasn't up yet, now it is)

Comment: I removed the bounty - GEOFF DALGAS WILL NEVER GET THAT BOUNTY :)

Comment: DAMN YOUU!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange developer [Geoff Dalgas](https://stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) has fixed this problem.

[His answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268663/3366929) to your [Meta.SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268162/3366929):

> I have audited our audit code and it should be faking up a low rep user and showing you the real rep after completion of the audit.

The usercard should now be anonymized on all audits (it always has been for me; I'm not sure why it wasn't working for you).

I'm just posting this here in case someone searches for it and comes across this post instead of the Meta.SO one. I've [mentioned it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268162/how-can-an-answer-posted-by-a-3-5k-rep-user-get-used-as-an-audit-in-the-first-p/268663#comment77830_268663) to Geoff, so if he posts an answer here, I'll delete this one.

Comment: I think he saw this answer. Because its *his* question, as you rightly mentioned ;)

Comment: @nicael I certainly hope so, but I posted it here for the sake of parity because I didn't expect Geoff to track down this post as well.

Comment: Or, to be more honest, to get the bounty :D

Comment: @nicael Well, he's the one who did the work of fixing it, so he deserves it more than I do. I [mentioned it to him](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268162/how-can-an-answer-posted-by-a-3-5k-rep-user-get-used-as-an-audit-in-the-first-p/268663#comment77830_268663) if he wants to post here.